# How to pass parameters to a template with a response redirect call to a root get request? [Express.js & Node.js]

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, ejs

```
//cards to be created in template
var coins = [];
var formattedCoins = [];    

app.get("/", function(req, res){
        for(x in formattedCoins){
            for(y in formattedCoins[x])
            console.log("From '/': " + formattedCoins[x][y].name);
        }

        res.render("coin.ejs", {coins: formattedCoins});
    });

    //retrieve form information
    app.post("/getCoin", function(req, res){

        var symbol = req.body.formSymbol;

        request("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/", function(error, response, body){
            //if no error and status is OK
                if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
                    //data returned are not JS objects application must parse JSON data first into JS
                    var parsedData = JSON.parse(body);
                    //find coin with the same symbol submitted
                    for(x in parsedData){
                        if(parsedData[x].symbol == symbol.toUpperCase()){

                            //create object
                            var newCoin = {
                                name: parsedData[x].name,
                                symbol: parsedData[x].symbol,
                                usd: parsedData[x].price_usd,
                                btc: parsedData[x].price_btc
                            };

                            //save coin to list
                                coins.push(newCoin);
                                //filter into 2D array
                                formatCoins();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

        res.redirect("/");
    });
```

Hey guys,

bear with me for the long slab of code I didn't know how to minimize it without leaving out anything important that might need to be looked at.

I'm currently making an application that pulls data from the 'coinmarket' API.

How I want the application to work is to render new data with the new coin received after making the post request and redirecting back to " / ". However, what happens is:

- Submit Form
- Server confirms that object was found and saved in the global array 'coins'.
- Format it into a 2D array that can be more easily rendered into the template.
- Redirect to " / " **(Here is where I want the formattedCoins to be rendered)**
- Attempt to render "coin.ejs" with 'formattedCoins' parameter to be passed.
- Page loads again without rendering 'formattedCoins'
- Submit the form again with no input
- Page renders with the new coin

I feel like I'm doing something wrong with how I'm routing the get request to " / " for object rendering.

Can I get some help guys? I can't see where the issue is.

Thanks!

Comment: you have to send it by url? like by `params` or by `query`.

Comment: I do, no? I call res.redirect("/"); from the post request and then from that function we call res.render("coin.ejs", {coins: formattedCoins}); and send 'formattedCoins' as 'coins' for the ejs template. @SaikatHajra

Comment: here what I see your `res.redirect` getting called before `request` complete. Async nature `Nodejs`

Comment: `res.redirect` should be after   `formatCoins` function if that function is not doing any IO operation. Otherwise put it just below ` coins.push`. It should work

Comment: Thank you very much (: @SaikatHajra